# SSH unavailable system booting

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I got a weird problem with a server from a hosting company. Sadly they don't give you IPMI/KVM access so all I got is the option to reinstall or boot up the server with their recovery image.

I'm certain that it would be easy to fix booting a rescue-cd like grml but sadly that's an option I don't have. So maybe someone can give me an advice how to procees further ...

- already reinstalled system twice, worked for a while - then same issue
- hosting company checked hardware and claim everything is ok
- recovery system does boot without issue

**The system**
Minimal Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install with basic iptables rules and percona server installed. Got several of those instances in another DC without any issue.

**The problem**
After reboot the system is not available over the network. The screen shows 'Starting OpenSSH daemon' and when I boot into recovery mode and check the logs there is no sign of issue.

I also tried to reinstall grub and set the network config to DHCP but nothing changed. I also disabled iptables but no matter what I tried, the system is still unavailable over the network.

Maybe someone got an idea here as I just don't want to reinstall this server every now and then.

Comment: Does the system appear to hang when starting the OpenSSH server? Could it perhaps be starved for entropy? (If so, we can probably devise a workaround.)

Comment: Honestly I don't know at least there was nothing suggesting this in syslog/dmesg etc. Besides this the system should reply to ping requests - or does the ssh daemon block network initialisation?
I'm not sure but I think that this also happens only when updates have been installed using apt. Though there's nothing suspicious in apt logs.

Comment: Oh. I totally missed the part about the system being completely non-responsive over the network. Sorry! Though I guess that leaves us with a different question: Is this an actual, physical, co-located server, or is it something else (a VM, maybe)?

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your effort. It's a physical (I think HP) server.